# Genetic Sharp - Optimization under constraints

Tags: geneticsharp

Is it possible to implement inegality constraints (linear or non-linear) in GeneticSharp?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement them in the fitness function, by penalizing chromosomes that breach the constraint with a outrageous penalty compared with the normal fitness ranges.

I have done it for a few problems and it worked fine.